# How get content from pfx certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate

How i get content like:

```
MIIC7jCCAdagAwIBAgIQRrjsbFPaXIlOG3GTv50fkjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAzMTEwLwYDVQQDEyh BREZTIFNpZ25pbmcgLSBXUzIwMTJSMi0wLnN3aW5mb3JtZXIuY29tMB4XDTE0MDEyMDE1MTY0MFoXDT E1MDEyMDE1MTY0MFowMzExMC8GA1UEAxMoQURGUyBTaWduaW5nIC0gV1MyMDEyUjItMC5zd2luZm9yb WVyLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAKe+rLVmXy1QwCwZwqgbbp1/kupQ VcjKuKLitVDbssFyqbDTjP7WRjlVMWAHBI3kgNT7oE362Gf2WMJFf1b0HcrsgLin7daRXpq4Qi6OA57 sW1YFMj3sqyuTP0eZV3S4+ZbDVob6amsZIdIwxaLP9Zfywg2bLsGnVldB0+XKedZwDbCLCVg+3ZWxd9 T/jV0hpLIIWr+LCOHqq8n8beJvlivgLmDJo8f+EITnAxWcsJUvVai/35AhHCUq9tc9sqMp5PWtabAEM b2AU72/QlX/72D2/NbGQq1BWYbqUpgpCZ2nSgvlWDHlCiUo//UGsvfox01kjTFlmqQInsJVfRxF5AcC AwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAi8c6C4zaTEc7aQiUgvnGQgCbMZbhUXXLGRpjvFLKaQzkwa9 eq7WLJibcSNyGXBa/SfT5wJgsm3TPKgSehGAOTirhcqHheZyvBObAScY7GOT+u9pVYp6raFrc7ez3c+ CGHeV/tNvy1hJNs12FYH4X+ZCNFIT9tprieR25NCdi5SWUbPZL0tVzJsHc1y92b2M2FxqRDohxQgJvy JOpcg2mSBzZZIkvDg7gfPSUXHVS1MQs0RHSbwq/XdQocUUhl9/e/YWCbNNxlM84BxFsBUok1dH/gzBy Sx+Fc8zYi7cOq9yaBT3RLT6cGmFGVYZJW4FyhPZOCLVNsLlnPQcX3dDg9A==
```

from certificate pfx file?

I do not understand certificates. What is this the format of the certificate? This is the decoded form?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to list what is inside pfx container?

keytool -v -list -storetype PKCS12 -keystore NAME_OF_THE_FILE.pfx -storepasswd 123456

keytool is the standard JDK utility.

Comment: for me is the only working command !

Answer (score 0):

The code which you provided doesn't corresponds for a PFX format; it is a PEM format. More information about what PFX(aka PKCS#12) format can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12.

A PEM file is just a base64 encoded [DER sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One#Example_encoded_in_DER) of a specific [ASN.1 notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One).

The basic ASN.1 structure of a x509 certificate can be found here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1

---

Your certificate file should look like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIC7jCCAdagAwIBAgIQRrjsbFPaXIlOG3GTv50fkjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAzMTEwLwYDVQQDEyh
BREZTIFNpZ25pbmcgLSBXUzIwMTJSMi0wLnN3aW5mb3JtZXIuY29tMB4XDTE0MDEyMDE1MTY0MFoXDT
E1MDEyMDE1MTY0MFowMzExMC8GA1UEAxMoQURGUyBTaWduaW5nIC0gV1MyMDEyUjItMC5zd2luZm9yb
WVyLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAKe+rLVmXy1QwCwZwqgbbp1/kupQ
VcjKuKLitVDbssFyqbDTjP7WRjlVMWAHBI3kgNT7oE362Gf2WMJFf1b0HcrsgLin7daRXpq4Qi6OA57
sW1YFMj3sqyuTP0eZV3S4+ZbDVob6amsZIdIwxaLP9Zfywg2bLsGnVldB0+XKedZwDbCLCVg+3ZWxd9
T/jV0hpLIIWr+LCOHqq8n8beJvlivgLmDJo8f+EITnAxWcsJUvVai/35AhHCUq9tc9sqMp5PWtabAEM
b2AU72/QlX/72D2/NbGQq1BWYbqUpgpCZ2nSgvlWDHlCiUo//UGsvfox01kjTFlmqQInsJVfRxF5AcC
AwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAi8c6C4zaTEc7aQiUgvnGQgCbMZbhUXXLGRpjvFLKaQzkwa9
eq7WLJibcSNyGXBa/SfT5wJgsm3TPKgSehGAOTirhcqHheZyvBObAScY7GOT+u9pVYp6raFrc7ez3c+
CGHeV/tNvy1hJNs12FYH4X+ZCNFIT9tprieR25NCdi5SWUbPZL0tVzJsHc1y92b2M2FxqRDohxQgJvy
JOpcg2mSBzZZIkvDg7gfPSUXHVS1MQs0RHSbwq/XdQocUUhl9/e/YWCbNNxlM84BxFsBUok1dH/gzBy
Sx+Fc8zYi7cOq9yaBT3RLT6cGmFGVYZJW4FyhPZOCLVNsLlnPQcX3dDg9A==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

if you have this certificate saved as `certificate.pem`, then you could read its content with openssl:

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in certificate.pem
```